# Convert AAC to WAV Mono channel from a URL to get Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

Having a **URL** to an **.AAC** file - How to convert  **AAC** to **WAV Mono Channel**  and get the corresponding **Byte []**

I have tried the following:

```cs
var outputStreamWAV = new MemoryStream();
var outputStreamWAVMono = new MemoryStream();

using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(audioFileURL))
{
    WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(outputStreamWAV , reader);
}

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(outputStream, **HOW TO CHOOSE THE WAVE FORMAT**);
var SampleProvider = new SampleChannel(new WaveToSampleProvider(provider).ToWaveProvider());
var mono = new StereoToMonoSampleProvider(SampleProvider);
WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(outputStreamMono, mono.ToWaveProvider());
```

Keeping in mind I only need those in memory and not save them as files.

- How to choose the **WaveFormat**?
- Is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: You decode the first file into a `byte[]` first, *then* you encode it using a new format. NAudio's repo contains links to a *lot* of examples that show how to convert directly (by going through the bytes), write out to WAV files, play the files etc. Have you tried anything? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Just by looking at the examples you can see there's an `AudioFileReader`. The raw bytes though aren't useful though, they're needed because you want to apply some filter or effect, play the stream or convert it to another format. NAudio can do these things already. What do you want to do with those bytes? There's probably a way to do exactly what you want already, or create a custom filter that plugs into NAudio's architecture

Comment: I need those to send them to Dialogflow Speech API as  - Please check my updated answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you please take another look at my updated answer and let me know if you have any advice, thank you

Comment: What does `HOW TO CHOOSE THE WAVE FORMAT` mean? How to select the sample rate or the number of bits? Pick whatever is appropriate. You have 1 channel anyway. Sample rate and bits affect quality and size, with 16-bit a typical value. [The doc samples](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/detect-intent-audio) use 16000Hz, 16 bit